# Nice template for writing a speech

Tags: templates

The title says it all. I think that a beautiful speech deserves to be written in a beautiful template. I can just simply take a basic article or something alike and type the speech, but as a LaTeX geek, I would like the speech to look wonderful. Possibilities for margin notes would be appreciated, they might give some clues to improvise in the middle of the speech.

Comment: Just a suggestion: how about `tufte`?

Comment: Good idea, thank you ! Although Gonzalo's answer does the trick right...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want your speech to look "wonderful", and "wonderfulness" is subjective. In my case, wonderfulness and sobriety are almost synonymous; below I present a possibility.

You can take the `article` document class and do some little customizations. In the following example I chose the article document class and use the following settings and packages:

- Font size `11pt` (or perhaps `12pt`) to facilitate reading.
- The [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for the page layout: `a5paper`, narrow right margin, generous left margin for marginal notes.
- The [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package to typeset marginal notes: using `\marginnote`, marginal notes are not floats. `\reversemarginpar` to guarantee marginal notes on the left margin.
- The [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package: I think that for a speech is convenient to have some vertical spacing between paragraphs and with no indentation for their first lines.
- The [`fwlw`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fwlw) (first word, last word) package and its `NextWordFoot` page style: having the possibility to read ahead to the word on the next page can be helpful.
- The micro-typographic features provided by the [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package.
- A nice font: I choose [`librebaskerville`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/librebaskerville).

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,lmargin=3.5cm,rmargin=25pt,bmargin=0.8cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{NextWordFoot}
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand*\marginfont{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
Some text\marginnote{Some initial remark here}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum*[4]\marginnote{Remember to mention something at this point}
\lipsum*[2]\marginnote{Don't forget to mention some people here}\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a wonderful example. I would just like to add that including a title with `\maketitle`, will somehow interfere with `NextWordFoot`, which does not appear at all on the first page. The remaining pages are fine.