# A generic but ready-to-use book template

Tags: templates, book-design, books

## Previous materials and purpose of a book template

Let's assume for a second: **I already have all the text** (content) done for a book. Now, I want to set it ready for auto-publishing, in the best punk-rock Do It Yourself [DIY] style. What can I do with LaTeX?

Let's get a bit more specific. Many questions on this site ask for templates in several fields:

- [Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94970/best-latex-templates-for-books-and-lecture-notes?rq=1) for example, and yes, as an answer there suggests `memoir` is generally a very good class for this purpose. In fact, that post informs of another post with a very functional [*painless template*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template). One of the few and *best book templates* in fact that I could find: code appears clearly and not too long, compiles well. Just that when I try to add more text it just doesn't work...
- Another post asks for a class to [write novels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73618/is-there-a-class-for-writing-novels). And of course comes the comment: *what features are you looking for?*. I'll be back on this point.
- Another post looks to use LaTeX for writing a fiction book. Here appears a good requirement that is quite simple and deserves some attention: **a ready-to-go template...for a book** . The above *painless template* more or less can serve this purpose of mwe as template. However I'd like some specifications that I mention as follows.

Sidenote: another cool template is the [tufte-book](https://tufte-latex.github.io/tufte-latex/), but it's not prepared for changes of page-size with geometry package... Hence some requirements...

---

## Ideas for a book template

Most books, as far as I check my bookshelf, are not made in a4 paper. So here a list of desirable basic possibilties for a **book template**.

#### Inside the book

- First foursih pages could have:

  1) title page with the title alone

  2) blank page

  3) title page with title and author name

  4) copyright, and other front matter info on the book/publisher
- Then: main matter/contents ...yada yada
- Others/index/bib/etc.
- Maybe date/place of publication at the end, and perhaps some other information.

#### Configuration

- Fit por papers of sizes other than a4. Could be different shape, or bigger or smaller than a4. I like a5, and a6.
- Set some kind of typography.
- As for style: this [template for a speech](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118049/nice-template-for-writing-a-speech), even if subjective, seems nice.

---

## Subjective scope and possible answers

Yes, all these pointers are somewhat arbitrary, but a **template book** shall come very handy and it's *a good place to start at* for those who have a ready text and want to format it for print. And I haven't seen this solidly responded elsewhere. I've browsed around and page title alone requires a whole series of consideration, same with typography, page size and so on.

This question aims not only for a variety of answers but also to achieving a code that could be not too long and somewhat clean with those basic points inside the book and maybe an additional tweak or so of configuring a style.

Granted that this is not very close to getting a *minimal* example. But I still feel that just these few requirements could be usefull for people planning to do a book. My pointers intend to go in the same direction as a comment-[link](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion) suggested:

> we can work together to establish some common standards of *best practice* (What does that even mean?) to improve the initial state of future templates and improve the current situation

That post has very good points. And references too (tl,dr). However, even if this question may be improved I still see some valid points and that it could be a good starting point.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is scratched. A *minimal* thing does not contain any other packages. Also, the concept of templates is scratched, you may want to read about the [confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion).

Comment: @Johannes_B granted that it wasn't minimal, and edited that. I understand the main idea of scratched but please add more info so that we can move forward. I really liked your [title page customization](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280). Maybe we can combine that answer with additional data for these requirements?

Comment: The topic of thesis templates came up a few weeks ago on [`c.t.t.`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/PhWqW7q8A_g) (<- Link). I have very strong feelings *against* templates, as you might have already noticed. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29508320#29508320

Comment: @Johannes_B I think we have a common ground on "the initial state of future templates", yes? If this were a pasta salad, and I lower my level and amount of questions to just one. How can I set proper code for a book with this structure: **the 4 1st pages** as set above (this is the most important part of the question, and seeking for clean code, and then...),contents, the end details?

Comment: if I could add just one more detail to the minimal question it´d be that it works on a non-a4-size-paper

Comment: You want something generic that fits with your specific ideas? All that is feasible is something generic that enables you to tweak it to get what you want. BTW the traditional place for publication date and place is not at the end but on your idea of a copyright page.

Comment: @PeterWilson generic would be the minimal requirements for a printed book with isbn. The specifications try to push in that direction. But others are welcome too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently posted a new document class, specifically for the purpose of a novel. It is not just a template, but a complete method for created a file in PDF/X for print-on-demand (paper, not e-book). You can find it on CTAN:

https://ctan.org/pkg/novel

It comes with elaborate documentation, directed toward writers rather than programmers. You may need to start from scratch, but that should not be difficult, as the document class is pre-configured for the most likely needs of book publishing.

You can also see a demonstration novel (from public domain) both in the LaTeX code and finished PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I know content is already done but for next writing it's good reminder that you can always focus the most on content, and using *stripped down writing software* is always a nice time. If you use plain text you can always use [markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114052/what-latex-lyx-classes-modules-and-templates-are-available-for-novel-writing) (+pandoc)

---

Now to the actual answer. I've set a book with **4 initial pages** as stated. Not sure if code is clean, or could get more minimal, but I can make modifications with little or no errors. It's set for **a6paper/landscape**. It's intended to be a book that has some text and some [pictures at full page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image). At the end it also has indication of printing and even a bar code.

Here the not so `mwe`, or rather more of *a ¿complete skeleton working example?*

(Side note: remember [the how-to for a mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{scrbook} 
%\input{packages}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage{incgraph,tikz} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{8.5cm} 
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000

\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\date{}

%\input{main-matter} 
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{7em}{\centering\Huge throwing up upwards \par}\clearpage
\newpage \thispagestyle{empty} \mbox{} \cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{7em}{\centering\Huge throwing up upwards \par}
    {\centering -- a guy with a heavy flu \par}\cleardoublepage
\newpage \thispagestyle{empty} \mbox{} \clearpage

\begin{mdframed} \begin{scriptsize} \noindent 
Author: X -- \\ 
Title: throwing up upwards. \\ 
1\textsuperscript{st} edition. nowhere. \\ 
1. Stuff 2. Literature 3. Astrology 4. Science 5. Crazy photography
\end{scriptsize} \end{mdframed}

\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{\fill} \parbox{.8\textwidth}{\raggedright \scriptsize
\textit{imposible} publisher 2016 

printed blindfolded

design: \LaTeX 
}
\end{titlepage} 
\clearpage \thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% QUOTE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\epigraph{one original thought is worth a thousand mindless quotings} 
{--- \textup{\textit{Banksy ...quoting Diogenes? }} } 
\vspace*{\fill} \cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage \cleardoublepage 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{plain}

\part{1} hey 

\incgraph[documentpaper,overlay={\node[red] at (page.center) {\Huge Picture sized to paper};}][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}

%\input{final}

\newpage \thispagestyle{empty} \mbox{} \clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}\hfill   \parbox{\textwidth}
{\scriptsize  \centering
printed in december\\ feeling that the year was still ok}

\newpage \thispagestyle{empty} \mbox{} \cleardoublepage 

\def\barcode#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\begingroup%
\dimen0=0.1em
\def\stack##1##2{\oalign{##1\cr\hidewidth##2\hidewidth}}%
\def\0##1{\kern##1\dimen0}%
\def\1##1{\vrule height10ex width##1\dimen0}%
\def\L##1{\ifcase##1\bc3211##1\or\bc2221##1\or\bc2122##1\or\bc1411##1%
\or\bc1132##1\or\bc1231##1\or\bc1114##1\or\bc1312##1\or\bc1213##1%
\or\bc3112##1\fi}%
\def\R##1{\bgroup\let\next\1\let\1\0\let\0\next\L##1\egroup}%
\def\G##1{\bgroup\let\bc\bcg\L##1\egroup}% reverse
\def\bc##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##1\1##2\0##3\1##4}##5}%
\def\bcg##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##4\1##3\0##2\1##1}##5}%
\def\bcR##1##2##3##4##5##6{\R##1\R##2\R##3\R##4\R##5\R##6\11\01\11\09%
\endgroup}%
\stack{\09}#1\11\01\11\L#2%
\ifcase#1\L#3\L#4\L#5\L#6\L#7\or\L#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\G#7%
\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\G#7\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\G#6\L#7%
\or\G#3\L#4\L#5\G#6\G#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\L#6\G#7%
\or\G#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\L#7\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\L#6\G#7%
\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\G#6\L#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\L#7%
\fi\01\11\01\11\01\bcR}

\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{\fill}
\centering{\barcode 9780029021408} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe it'd be nice if you can set all pictures on odd sides... this way if the paper is of limited quality it doesn't superpose with images in next/previous pages...

Comment: `\cleardoublepage\newpage\mbox{}\clearpage`? KOMA-script provides commands like `\cleartooddpage` that you might like.

Comment: Why are you setting the global option `openany`?

Comment: @Johannes_B ...I didn't know about `\cleartooddpage`, that's great. I used `openany` so that _text appears on even pages_ after sections, and that way I could describe at length _a picture on a odd page_, on the other side. Makes sense?

Comment: kpfonts *and* baskervald?

Comment: @Thérèse yup, that's for old style numbers added to the baskervald typography. Have an opinion? Please tell me what you think. All ideas are welcome.

Comment: That’s mixing an old-style serif into a transitional serif.  If you can’t use Open Type fonts, there’s support for the (commercial) Berthold Baskerville, with lowercase figures, at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt. And if you can’t buy a commercial font, have a look at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/boisik for a Metafont typeface, with lowercase figures, inspired by Baskerville.

Comment: very nice Boisik suggestion!! however it's still at alpha

Comment: I don't approve, but if it will stop you doing this, try `Baskervaldx`. Again, I wouldn't and I think you shouldn't. But it is better than mixing `kpfonts` with `baskervald`.

Comment: @Thérèse `Baskervaldx` is a better option than mixing `kpfonts`, surely?

Comment: @cfr A better option than `boisik`, you mean? I don’t know, since I don’t use either in my own documents; old-style French and Venetians fit my subject matter.  The sense of my comment was that adding `kpfonts` to the mix will produce visual cacophony.

Comment: @Thérèse No. Better than `kpfonts`/`baskervald` since the OP seemed not to want to use `boisik`. (I would have thought if you were desperate enough to try that mix, you'd welcome something who's only downside is that it is alpha, but stable cacophony is apparently preferable.) I have no view on `boisik` vs. `Baskervaldx` as I've never used either.

Comment: @Thérèse I just though `Baskervaldx` was an obvious suggestion and was wondering if you had some reason not to suggest it, really.

Comment: If I had a reason (but August is a distant memory), it was probably one of the things I jotted down in my file of notes on fonts: that it’s a poor imitation of Baskerville, and that its use of `rlig` and `c2sc` is odd. By ‘odd,’ I mean that `rlig` turns ae, Ae, AE, oe, Oe, and OE into æ, Æ, œ, and Œ, which produces words like ‘pœtry’ if you’re not careful. Of course, that may not affect people who use it with `pdftex` and the `baskervaldx` package, and I have no notes on that.